# How to select and copy entire row based on text-value in a cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I would like to do the following:

1. Find all cells containing a certain keyword in a column in an excel spreadsheet.
2. Select and copy the **entire row** which includes the cells which have the keyword mentioned in point 1)
3. Paste these new rows into a separate spreadsheet.

I know you can select all rows including a certain term using "Find and select" and then hitting CTRL+A, but this feature only helps you delete the rows that include the keyword, and not copy them into a separate spreadsheet.

Please see the image below as an example. I want to find and copy the rows which include the keyword "MVD" in column D and paste them in a new Excel.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwHXk.png)

Comment: add a filter, then filter it.

Answer (score 2):

As `gns100` commented, you can add a filter to the lookup column, then filter. Copy and paste the resulting material (`Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-C`, go to the other spreadsheet, `Ctrl-V`, then return and clear the filter).

Another way, very similar, but perhaps would work nicely for you is to set up a `FILTER()` function in the other spreadsheet. Address the source material with absolute, or dynamic, references, and set up a cell to hold the lookup term (or after pasting the formula, edit the second parameter) and make its reference absolute.

For example, data in A1:C10, lookup in D1:

```
=FILTER($A$1:$C$10,$A$1:$A$10=$D$1)
```

To use, enter the desired lookup term, copy and paste the stock formula, it gives its results with the upper left cell selected/highlighted, and you just use `Shift-End-Down-Right` to select the whole block it added. Copy and `Paste|Special|Values` to have the results, not the formula.

Of course, the formula would go neatly into a Named Range and you would just need to give it the lookup value, then type "=Named Range" to achieve that more easily. Though it is pretty short and simple, so if not doing it a dozen or a hundred times a day, just typing it out on the fly would be pretty easy.

And either approach could be set up using VBA. Just the macro recorder for the one here, and the macro recorder with an edit for the filter function approach.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the Advanced filter:
Go to **Data**- **Advanced**- enter the Criteria:

[image]